# Guard let is executing, but the code after it still works?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, guard

Ok, so I have a MapKit app, and just finished setting up the MKAnnotationView stuff.  My MKAnnotationView class looks like this:

```
class JumpSpotAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        // Extra safe, making sure there's no errors
        guard (newValue as? JumpSpotAnnotation) != nil else {
            print("The JumpSpotAnnotation or JumpSpotAnnotationView has something wrong if you are reading this. (JumpSpotAnnotationView)")
            return
        }
        // Setting up UI for the little Callout bubble that appears when you tap the annotation to see more info
        canShowCallout = true
        calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        //detailCalloutAccessoryView
        markerTintColor = .blue
    }
}
}
```

And my mapView viewFor function in my view controller looks like this:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
    // Make sure the annotation entering the screen is a JumpSpotAnnotation, and exists
    guard let annotation = annotation as? JumpSpotAnnotation else {
        print("The JumpSpotAnnotation or JumpSpotAnnotationView has something wrong if you are reading this. (mapView viewFor func)")
        return nil
    }
    // Downcast the dequeued view as a JumpSpotAnnotationView, and make sure it has the same identifier as the registered JumpSpotAnnotationView above in viewDidLoad
    let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "JumpSpotAnnotation") as? JumpSpotAnnotationView
    dequeuedView?.annotation = annotation
    // Return annotation views here
    return dequeuedView
}

}
```

Honestly, I put the guard let's in each of those, because I saw someone else do it that way and assumed it would be safer.  I'm not really sure what their purpose is, other than making sure an annotation is actually entering the view, and is of the right type of annotation that I specified (I think it does that, at least).

Anyway, when I actually add the annotations by pressing a button in my app, everything works flawlessly, exactly as I want it to, but the print statements inside of the guard let's are showing up in the debugger.  I have no idea what's causing them, nor any idea why my code is still working after they've triggered, when the fact that the guard let's have executed should stop the code below them from executing, and mess up my app.  Can anyone offer ideas or explanations? I should add that the print statement from the mapView viewFor func appears once, as soon as the app loads up, then, the print statement from my JumpSpotAnnotationView appears each time I add an annotation.

I want to make sure I'm not missing some huge error that I'll regret down the line.

Comment: Don't you think understanding `guard` statements would be a good place to start, with tackilng this problem?

Comment: How many annotaions items do you have on a map?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I do understand them for the most part, you set a condition, and if it fails, the else statement executes.  Am I wrong? If I am please educate me I am fairly new.  To the other Alexander - there is no set amount of annotation items, I can add as many as I please in my simulator.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I supposed I was unclear in my question. when I said "I'm not really sure what their purpose is" I didn't mean guard statements in general, I meant these specific ones

Comment: Are you sure the annotation view being rendered is actually your JumpSpotAnnotation class? It seems as if it would actually be the default annotation view. The guard in willSet doesn't prevent the variable from being set, and the guard in mapView(_:viewFor:) returning nil tells the map to use default annotation

Comment: @Dale Yes I am sure, I can even click on the annotation and it has the correct title that I input before its creation.  my app has a screen where you can specify the elements of each annotation, one of which being the title.  The callout displays the name I specifically input when creating it

Comment: ... and is the callout accessory shown?

Comment: @Dale Yup! That's why this is so weird

Comment: Try adding some logging AFTER the guard statement and do some accounting. How many times is  mapView(_:viewFor:) being called  and how many annotations are appearing.

Comment: @Dale I added the print statement "passed" after the guard lets to really make sure the code is executing (is that what you mean by logging?), and sure enough it shows up in the debugger.  judging by that, mapView(_:viewFor:) is being called once when the annotation is added, and the first time the annotation re-enters the view if it was moved off view, it is called.  It doesn't seem to be called the second or more times that you move it off the view and have it re-enter.

Comment: @Dale in terms of how many annotations are appearing, when I press the button that creates my annotation, one annotation appears exactly where and how I want it to

Comment: Are you showing the users location (blue dot] on the map?  That is an annotation and `viewForAnnotation` will be called for that annotation. That annotation is not an instance of `JumpSpotAnnotation`.

Comment: yup, pretty sure that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some MKAnnotations that are not the class of JumpSpotAnnotation when `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` works. It must be from MKMapView so dont worry about it. Your `guard let` works well.

Comment: are you reffering to something like the userLocation? Because I have that activated as well, maybe that's it?  Thanks for the help

Comment: @derek I think that's the possible reason. The MKMapView make a MKAnnotation automatically.